# XAMPP wont load htdocs domain sites

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, backup

I wanted to update old version of PHP on my windows server R12 2012 , I made backup of my available sites and whole folder containing it , both with the database , after that I deleted old XAMPP and installed new one , put HTTDOC folder back in and database , but for some reason I am only able to see INDEX.PHP file when I try to resolve any domains.

Comment: Do you use a virtual host in the old version?

Comment: no, i tried copying httpd.conf but still same problem

Comment: i added virtual host , now i am getting Error establishing a database connection

Comment: Check DB connection credential and make sure MySQL server is running.